# RewriteRule variables blank

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I have a couple of rewrite rules in htaccess. They work on one server but not another. My script is as follows (I've commented out how the urls look):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/

#example.com/regions/fife/
RewriteRule ^regions/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+\']+)/?$ /regions.php?region=$1 [L]

#example.com/regions/fife/dunfermline
RewriteRule ^regions/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /regions.php?region=$1&town=$2 [L]
```

It returns two variables (region & town) I can manipulate in PHP, and throw up the appropriate content. I have a Rackspace server, and the script works perfectly, but on another server (Freedom2surf) it only works so far. It doesn't return the variables. I get a blank $_GET array...

Any ideas? F2S aren't giving me any clues, just that I should check my code. But if it works on another server, then what gives? Is it an Apache setting that is different?

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the new host? What is the URL you're receiving in your script ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?

Comment: My host says that they have mod_rewrite enabled, and I see this: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = /regions/fife/dunfermline

If it didn't work, then I guess I would just be seeing a 404 error page? But it is actually taking me to regions.php, just not displaying the variables.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? I'm having the same one right now.

Comment: Note: the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/   is erroneous, it has no RewriteRule associated with it, so will just slow the first regions rule down. I'd suggest you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be after the 'QSA' flag, which will append the query string from the original request to the redirected request, e.g:

```
#example.com/regions/fife/
RewriteRule ^regions/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+\']+)/?$ /regions.php?region=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have a mod_negotiation conflict here and you need to turn Multiviews **off**. Sometimes apache default configurations have `Multiviews` turned on by default. What that does is it will look at a request, say, `/regions/1234` and mod_negotiation will notice that there is a file `/regions.php` and assume that the request is actually for that php file. It'll thus serve `/regions.php/1234` and completely bypass mod_rewrite. You can use `Options` to turn it off. Just add this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```